# sails.js addToCollection Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I'm new with node.js, sails.js and javascript in general. I'm am trying to do a personal website for domotics applications at home.

In the process of creating the this sails.js app, i'm stuck with one problem when i try to use the addToCollection function in a many-to-many association.

here is my code:

// dashboard.js

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    owner: {
      model: 'user',
      unique: true
    },
    boxs: {
      collection: 'box',
      via: 'views'
    }
  }
};
```

//box.js
    module.exports = {

```
  attributes: {
      x: {
        type: 'integer',
        required: true
      },
      y: {
        type: 'integer',
        required: true
      },
      moduleinfo: {
        model: 'device',
        unique: true
      },
      views: {
        collection: 'dashboard',
        via: 'boxs'
      }
  }
};
```

when somewhere in my code (after i created a box and a dashboard) i try to call the addToCollection function i get an error:

```
Dashboard.findOne({owner: req.session.User.id}).exec(function(err, dashboard){
    await Dashboard.addToCollection(dashboard.id, 'boxs', box.id);
});
```

here is the log:

```
info: Starting app...
error: A hook (`controllers`) failed to load!
error: `include-all` attempted to `require(/home/benjamin/Documents/nodejs/automathomejs/api/controllers/DeviceController.js)`, but an error occurred:: 
Details:SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/include-all/lib/help-include-all-sync.js:271:33
at Array.forEach (native)
at _recursivelyIncludeAll (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/include-all/lib/help-include-all-sync.js:174:11)
at includeAll (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/include-all/lib/help-include-all-sync.js:292:5)
at helpBuildDictionary (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/include-all/lib/help-build-dictionary.js:43:15)
at Function.module.exports.optional (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/include-all/index.js:67:10)
at Hook.loadControllers (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/moduleloader/index.js:324:18)
at Hook.wrapper [as loadControllers] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3250:19)
at Hook.loadAndRegisterControllers (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/controllers/to-load-and-register-controllers.js:33:19)
at Hook.initialize (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/controllers/index.js:59:12)
at Hook.wrapper [as initialize] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3250:19)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/index.js:88:16
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:548:17
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:542:17
```

Thank you for your time!

Benjamin

Answer (score 0):

There is alot to unpack here.

First in Sails.js this error :

```
error: `include-all` attempted to `require(/home/benjamin/Documents/nodejs/automathomejs/api/controllers/DeviceController.js)`, but an error occurred:: Details:SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Usually means you have a typo somewhere.

Your code here:

```
Dashboard.findOne({owner: req.session.User.id}).exec(function(err, dashboard){
await Dashboard.addToCollection(dashboard.id, 'boxs', box.id);});
```

First `.exec` is old and shouldn't really be used with Sails.js
Also you can't use `.exec` AND `await` together.

That being said `await` has to be inside an async function.

Also the organization of your code is confusing. You need to work vertically rather then horizontally as you have it.

Here is an example of how to go about reworking your code:

```
Good

var result = await whatever();//1
var result2 = await whatever2();//2


Bad (old)

//1
  whatever((err, result)=>{
  //2
   whatever2((err, result2)=>{
    //3
    })
  });
```

More information

https://github.com/mikermcneil/parley/tree/bf09a3abee35446217e799d057505a2eaf593172#flow-control

Answer (score 0):

await can only be used in async function.So you can try this: 
Put aync before your function.

```
Dashboard.findOne({owner: req.session.User.id}).exec(async function(err, dashboard){
await Dashboard.addToCollection(dashboard.id, 'boxs', box.id);
```

});